# Fetching rows added in the last hour using Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, laravel-5.1

I am working on a project in which I have to track all the records which are added in last hour of current time.

I am able to do this by using following query,

```
select count(*) as cnt
from  log
where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

but not able to do the same in Laravel.

Comment: What laravel code have you tried so far? Are you using Eloquent or the query builder?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the Carbon date time api to get the last hour formated datetime

```
$count = \DB::table('logs')->where('date', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHour())->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Db::raw

```
$count = \DB::table('log') ->where(\DB::raw('date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)')) ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with this

```
\DB::table('log')->where(['date' => DB::raw('DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR)')])->count();
```

Comment: Can you privide some explanation what your code does? Code only answers might not be that useful for other people...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DB::raw()` to execute special query parts.

Like so:

```
$count = \DB::table('log')
    ->where('date', '>=', \DB::raw('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)'))
    ->count();
```

Comment: ok i tried this, but it giving me 0 result, where there are so many entries in the current hour

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot the `>=` in the where function. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I updated a bit your commnet. 
$count = \DB::table('log')
    ->where(\DB::raw('date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)'))
    ->count();